# OBJECT to FLOAT in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df_encoded.head()
Time    Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4  Q5  Q6  Q7  Q8  Q9  ... Q31 Q33 Q36 Q38 Q42 Q44 Q45 Q47 Q49 Q50
0   3746    0   3   56  3   1   7   7   0   4152    ... [1, 5, 9, 10]   [6, 2, 0, 1, 3] [1, 11] 19  0   5   5   [54, 55, 97]    [11, 8, 10] 8
1   3778    1   1   21  3   8   4   7   0   8541    ... 1   11  [10, 0, 13, 1]  [9, 2]  1   [0, 1]  [0, 5]  39  9   [8, 4]
2   4261    1   4   8   1   7   11  0   2   870 ... [1, 5, 9]   3   1   13  3   4   4   91  [18, 19, 5, 2, 1, 0, 7, 19, 5, 3, 7, 17, 6, 4,...   [7, 1]
3   1180    1   0   21  3   7   11  16  0   4103    ... [4, 5, 8, 9]    [2, 0, 1, 5, 10]    [10, 4, 11] [19, 20, 9, 11] [5, 0]  4   [0, 4, 6]   54  [16, 12, 11, 9] 4
4   3823    1   3   19  3   2   17  15  7   3251    ... [5, 8, 9, 10]   [2, 0, 1, 7, 1, 5, 4]   10  13  5   4   [4, 6]  [54, 47, 97, 98]    [19, 5, 2, 1, 0, 7, 12, 11, 8, 10]  [8, 0]
```

the type of data in all columns are object. I can easily change the type from OBJECT to int or float for the columns that they are not any list in them. But as you can see through the data frame, there are some column which have list in it and I can not change their type from OBJECT to Float.....Is there any solution for it?

Finally, I want to have correlation matrix. but with having object, I can not have df_encoded.corr() in the columns with object type data. This correlation matrix is needed for making a heatmap.

Answer (score 1):

What do you need to achieve?

If you definitely know you can only solve your problem with having a row that contains a list and the objects in that list need to be float then you will probable need to iterate over every row. If you have a huge dataset, i.e. millions of rows, then you might need to rethink what you are trying to achieve.

To simply convert the rows you would need to use `.apply`, which iterates over each row in a pandas dataframe and allows you to perform an action on that row, in this case changing the types in that row. A quick win may be to use `numpy.array`.

```
import numpy as np

df_encoded['Q31'] = df_encoded.apply(
    lambda x: np.array(x['Q31']).astype(float),
    axis=1
)
```

Comment: Thank you eric. with this code, I received this error:   ValueError: ('setting an array element with a sequence.', 'occurred at index Q31')
I need to change the data types from object to int in the columns which there are lists. After that I want to plot a heat map from my data

Comment: ah you might be iterating over wrong axis, and also over whole dataset. im going to fix the code to `df_encoded.apply(lambda x: np.array(x['Q31']).astype(float), axis=1)`

Comment: with this code, there will be no error and I received this: 0                                  [1.0, 5.0, 9.0, 10.0]
1                                                    1.0
2                                        [1.0, 5.0, 9.0]
3                                   [4.0, 5.0, 8.0, 9.0]
but when I check dtypes, it is still object

Comment: its an array of floats, so it will be object, not float

Comment: so I can not transform them to int64 and I can not have a heatmap from them. ture?

Comment: int64 is not float... again youre going to need to provide more information

Comment: It should be something except object. what information do you need?

Comment: update your question with the code for the plot that you need

Comment: Thank you Eric. Updated